Summarize a Project List with multiple attributes
I have a list of projects by name in column a, in column b I have a list of statuses (not started, pre planned, planning, fieldwork, reported), in the next 15 columns I have mission areas these projects relate too(possible 71 unique mission areas). These 15 columns are filled with the mission areas or blank.  Some projects have one mission area while others have 6 or 7. How do I summarize by mission area? So I know the projects in each mission area (even show the zero values) and the status of each mission area project?
Example of data
Row 1: project name 1: planning: AP: AR:Europe:Contract: next 11 columns blank
Row 2: project name 2: not started: contract: next 14 columns blank
Row 3: project name 3: reporting: Contract: AP next 11 columns blank
Result needed:
AP:2(count): project name 1: planning: project name 3: reporting
AR:1:  project name 1: planning
Europe:1: project name 1: planning
Contracting:3: project name 1: planning: project name 2: not started: project name 3: reporting

Better to post data as markdown table. Like this we can't tell where a cell starts/ends, or if it's all in one cell even. https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables also share your attempt and why you need our help.

Without seeing a proper table it's difficult to make a recommendation; however, it looks like you could use Power Query to Unpivot your  mission area columns. This normalizes your data. You can filter the resulting table by mission area to see the associated projects and statuses.

If you have the list of areas in S2 and down, it can be the solution:

T2 and down =TEXTJOIN(" ; ";;BYROW(FILTER($A$2:$B$4;BYROW($C$2:$Q$4;LAMBDA(a;OR(a=S2))));LAMBDA(b;TEXTJOIN(":";;b))))

or, with the comma separator

=TEXTJOIN(" ; ",,BYROW(FILTER($A$2:$B$4,BYROW($C$2:$Q$4,LAMBDA(a,OR(a=S2)))),LAMBDA(b,TEXTJOIN(":",,b))))

in the structured layout form

=TEXTJOIN(
    " ; ",
    ,
    BYROW(
        FILTER(
            $A$2:$B$4,
            BYROW($C$2:$Q$4,LAMBDA(a,OR(a=S2)))
        ),
        LAMBDA(b,TEXTJOIN(":",,b))
    )
)

